# Event when postmessage() receives c#

Tags: c#, delphi

I have an unmanaged DLL with delphi and integrated there are some events that fire at certain points on runtime. 
On its manual it says that it calls the Win32 api `PostMessage()`.

When the event is fired a text message is sent and wParam and IParam have some other information.

How can i fire an event from my c# application when a message from the dll is posted and ofcourse get the information?

UPDATE:

Trying to describe what the manual is saying:
So i have a function called init() which accepts the handle parameter which i am passing as follows:

```
wr.Init((IntPtr)this.Handle);
```

from the c# Winform application to the unmanaged dll which returns true if it is fine and that is what i am seeing.

Now the manual says:

> When event (from the dll) is fired it sends a windows message to the window handle supplied with the Init function, infact PostMessage() Win32 API is called.

And i have the list of the messages that are sent on the PostMessage() for example:

```
TextMessage: WM_TECH_BROKENLINE
wParam: Point (which is a number displaying for example where is broken)
IParam: 0
```

Now as i explained i want that when a message like the one above is posted from the dll i fire an event from c# and ofcourse get the text message and the Params

Answer (score 1):

The steps necessary are as follows:

1. Obtain a window handle for a window in your C# program.
2. Pass that window handle to the unmanaged DLL so that it knows where to send the messages.
3. In your C# code, add code to receive and respond to the message arriving.

As an alternative to the above you might prefer to keep the GUI windows of your program separate from this message passing mechanism. In which case do the following:

1. Create a subclass of [`NativeWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) to handle incoming messages.
2. Create an instance of your class and pass its window handle to the unmanaged DLL.
3. Override `WndProc` in your window class and then handle the message there. At which point you can surface it as an event.

This latter approach gives better separation of your interop code from your GUI, and will allow you to make your wrapper less tangled with your GUI.

In order to describe any of this in more detail, one would need to know the details of your program. For instance, is it WinForms or WPF? Does your program have a window at hand to receive messages? How is the string encoded? In which message arg does it arrive? How is memory for the string deallocated if the message is delivered asynchronously?

I suspect you'll have answers to some of these questions, but perhaps not all. You now know at a high level what you need to do, but now need to find out more details for your own program.

Comment: So sorry for giving few information. It is a Winforms application in c# and i already obtained a window handle and sent it to the unmanaged dll but now i don't know how to grab the event

Comment: I answered the question that you asked with a matching amount of detail. The question and answer remain well matched. Perhaps your next task is to invest the time needed to make the question detailed enough to elicit the answer you desire.

Comment: Updated the question maybe can help more but that is all the information i have unfortunatly :/

Comment: I don't see how we can give more detail. You need to get more information. The next tasks are for you not us.

Comment: From your answer all i need to know is how to create part of number 3, which is adding code to receive the arriving message

Comment: Override `WndProc` on the form whose handle you passed to the DLL.

Comment: I am doing it from another class which handles the unmanaged dll, and it it is saying no suitable method to ovveride

Comment: You have to do what I said. Override `WndProc` on the form whose handle you passed to the dll. Or, perhaps, create a message only window by p/invoking `CreateWindow` and let that window handle the message. Probably how I would do it.

Comment: Even if the events and postmessage is going to be handled from another class?

Comment: I've added an alternative. With a message only window.

Comment: Thats sounds a good idea i have to find how to use CreateWindow

Comment: Actually it's probably easier to use `NativeWindow`.

Comment: Is it possible to maybe post an example on how to use NativeWindow in this setting?

Comment: There's a link in the answer with example code. There are countless examples around the web. I think I answered the broad question with a broad answer. I've spent plenty of time going deeper. I'm not sure it's fair to expect me to write the rest of the code for you. I suggest you spend some of your own time now doing research on `NativeWindow`. Do that in a test bend environment rather than in the production code. It will be much more productive that way. Don't look for silver bullets. Expect this learning process to take some time.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `WndProc` method of the form which handle you're passing to the dll. An example can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx

A simplified example for your case (add it into your form class):

```
    const int WM_TECH_BROKENLINE = 0x0401;  // It's WM_USER + 1 in my example.
                                            // Set it according to you dll's spec
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_TECH_BROKENLINE)
        {
                long dataPassedFromTheDll = (long)m.WParam;
                // Your stuff here:
                this.Text = string.Format("The dll sent us: {0}", dataPassedFromTheDll);
        } 
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: A function from the dll needs as a parameter that i pass the handle so that is not a concern... All i need is that i fire an event when there is something posted on the Win32 so i can fire an event on the c# side and ofcourse get the information posted by the DLL